# background-image and size in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need a Poly-fill that works for background-images and background-size on a div or section in IE8 or any other method?

```
.subcontainer {
 background: url(images/home-04.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader (src='images/home- 04.jpg',sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/home-   04.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
height: 320px;
}

 <section class="subcontainer">
    <article id="front_top">
      <div id="front_topcontent">
        <p>Investing with Discipline. <br>
               Designing so so sand so <br>
                    </p>

      </div>
           </article>
 </section>
```

Comment: Hi @Sadkie. Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question could use some work. Could you explain more clearly what you have already and where the hangup is?

Comment: I'm building a responsive website and on the home page i have a container that holds a vertical menu. The container has a background image that stretches on other browser but doesn't stretch in IE8. In fact I loose almost 40 pixels on the right of the container.